# ajax_command_invoke adding a new item in a field collection

Tags: ajax, entities

I'm using the field_collection module.
A collection has a "custom field" I've created, which rely on a jQuery plugin.
When I add another item in my collection, the jQuery plugin is no more invoked, and the field doesn't work anymore.

At the first load, all is working, it's only after adding a new item.

I don't know how to invoke the jQuery plugin initialization, there is probably something with the ajax command "field_add_more_js", but I can't figure out which hook or which solution I can use :(

Do you have any idea ?
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was quite simple... I use **[Drupal.behaviors](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal)** to attach my jQuery plugin initialization to the form, and it's now called on ajax callback as well, when a part of the form is updated by this ajax call.
So it's fixed !

The [drupal documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722) helped me, and the Lullabot article as well !